# how to fix error code for compare the variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Alice and Bob each created one problem for HackerRank. A reviewer rates the two challenges, awarding points on a scale from 1 to 100 for three categories: problem clarity, originality, and difficulty.

The rating for Alice's challenge is the triplet a = (a[0], a[1], a[2]), and the rating for Bob's challenge is the triplet b = (b[0], b[1], b[2]).

The task is to find their comparison points by comparing a[0] with b[0], a[1] with b[1], and a[2] with b[2].

```
If a[i] > b[i], then Alice is awarded 1 point.
If a[i] < b[i], then Bob is awarded 1 point.
If a[i] = b[i], then neither person receives a point.
```

Comparison points is the total points a person earned.

Given a and b, determine their respective comparison points.

Example

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 2, 1]

```
For elements *0*, Bob is awarded a point because a[0] .
For the equal elements a[1] and b[1], no points are earned.
Finally, for elements 2, a[2] > b[2] so Alice receives a point.
```

The return array is [1, 1] with Alice's score first and Bob's second.

Function Description

Complete the function compareTriplets in the editor below.

compareTriplets has the following parameter(s):

```
int a[3]: Alice's challenge rating
int b[3]: Bob's challenge rating
```

Return

```
int[2]: Alice's score is in the first position, and Bob's score is in the second.
```

Input Format

The first line contains 3 space-separated integers, a[0], a[1], and a[2], the respective values in triplet a.
The second line contains 3 space-separated integers, b[0], b[1], and b[2], the respective values in triplet b.

Constraints

```
1 ≤ a[i] ≤ 100
1 ≤ b[i] ≤ 100
```

Comment: What is your problem? Is this a programming exercise for us?

Comment: Related challenge question from  [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/compare-the-triplets/problem)

Comment: '_how to fix error code..._' which error?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def rate(alice, bob):
    alice_score = sum(a > b for a, b in zip(alice, bob))
    return [alice_score, 3 - alice_score]


def parse(participant_count=2):
    return (map(int, input().split()) for _ in range(participant_count))


print("Score is", rate(*parse()))
```

Example :

```py
1 2 3
3 1 2
Score is [2, 1]
```

Comment: Can you please try to illustrate what is the problem you are answering?

Comment: Oh sure, it's [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/compare-the-triplets/problem) problem from hackerrank that OP is trying to solve with exact same definition and constraints. @habrewning

Comment: But the answer is already on hackerrank.

Comment: I wasn't able to find it and just happen to write my own answer and it seems to correlate with what OP asked for. @habrewning